# Make Python dictionary available to all spark partitions

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, nearest-neighbor, pyspark

I am trying to develop an algorithm in pyspark for which I am working with linalg.SparseVector class. I need to create a dictionary of key value pairs as input to each SparseVector object. Here the keys have to be integers as they represent integers (in my case representing user ids). I have a separate method that reads the input file and returns a dictionary where each user ID ( string) is mapped to an integer index. When I go through the file again and do a

FileRdd.map( lambda x: userid_idx[ x[0] ] ) . I receive a KeyError. I'm thinking this is because my dict is unavailable to all partitions. Is there a way to make userid_idx dict available to all partitions similar to a distributed map in MapReduce? Also I apologize for the mess. I am posting this using my phone. Will update in a while from my laptop.

The code as promised:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark import SparkContext
import glob
import sys
import time
"""We create user and item indices starting from 0 to #users and 0 to #items respectively. This is done to store them in sparseVectors as dicts."""
def create_indices(inputdir):
    items=dict()
    user_id_to_idx=dict()
    user_idx_to_id=dict()
    item_idx_to_id=dict()
    item_id_to_idx=dict()
    item_idx=0
    user_idx=0
    for inputfile in glob.glob(inputdir+"/*.txt"):
        print inputfile
        with open(inputfile) as f:
            for line in f:
                toks=line.strip().split("\t")
                try:
                    user_id_to_idx[toks[1].strip()]
                except KeyError:
                    user_id_to_idx[toks[1].strip()]=user_idx
                    user_idx_to_id[user_idx]=toks[1].strip()
                    user_idx+=1
                try:
                    item_id_to_idx[toks[0].strip()]
                except KeyError:
                    item_id_to_idx[toks[0].strip()]=item_idx
                    item_idx_to_id[item_idx]=toks[0].strip()
                    item_idx+=1
    return user_idx_to_id,user_id_to_idx,item_idx_to_id,item_id_to_idx,user_idx,item_idx

# pass in the hdfs path to the input files and the spark context.
def runKNN(inputdir,sc,user_id_to_idx,item_id_to_idx):
    rdd_text=sc.textFile(inputdir)
    try:

        new_rdd = rdd_text.map(lambda x: (item_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[0])],{user_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[1])]:1})).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x.update(y))
    except KeyError:
        sys.exit(1)
    new_rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:path_to_output/user/hadoop/knn/output")

if __name__=="__main__":
    sc = SparkContext()
    u_idx_to_id,u_id_to_idx,i_idx_to_id,i_id_to_idx,u_idx,i_idx=create_indices(sys.argv[1])
    u_idx_to_id_b=sc.broadcast(u_idx_to_id)
    u_id_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(u_id_to_idx)
    i_idx_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(i_idx_to_id)
    i_id_to_idx_b=sc.broadcast(i_id_to_idx)
    num_users=sc.broadcast(u_idx)
    num_items=sc.broadcast(i_idx)
    runKNN(sys.argv[1],sc,u_id_to_idx_b.value,i_id_to_idx_b.value)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

Comment: @NickChammas I posted the code above. I am still receiving a keyError in the runKNN() method even though I pass in the broadcast variable values in? Or should I be passing in the actual broadcast variable pointers and invoking the .value() method inside the function?

Comment: actually tried that as well and I'm still seeing KeyErrors on the item_id_to_idx[ ]  part. And I checked whether the item key is present in the actual dictionary and it is. So the only reason I can think of is that I am not passing the broadcast variables properly.

Answer (score 6):

In Spark, that dictionary will already be available to you as it is in all tasks. For example:

```
dictionary = {1:"red", 2:"blue"}
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2])
rdd.map(lambda x: dictionary[x]).collect()
# Prints ['red', 'blue']
```

You will probably find that your issue is actually that your dictionary does not contain the key you are looking up!

From the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables):

> Normally, when a function passed to a Spark operation (such as map or reduce) is executed on a remote cluster node, it works on separate copies of all the variables used in the function. These variables are copied to each machine, and no updates to the variables on the remote machine are propagated back to the driver program.

A copy of local variables referenced will be sent to the node along with the task.

[Broadcast variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) will not help you here, they are simply a tool to improve performance by sending *once per node* rather than a *once per task*.

Comment: No it is not the issue that the key is not contained because I retrieve the actual dictionary object (just for testing) and query it on the exact key(s) that I received a KeyError on and each of the keys were present. And more-so it cannot be the case that my dictionary object doesn't have the key because I read the same input file to populate the dictionaries as I do to generate the RDD later on.  Unless I'm missing something here.  @dpeacock.   Unless it is the case that my method of populating dictionaries is running on different nodes and the dictionaries themselves are partitioned?

Comment: Your method for populating the dictionary is *not* running on different nodes, and the dictionary is not partitioned, you are running it on the driver node before even accessing the RDD.

Note you are creating the keys as:

item_id_to_idx[line.strip().split("\t")[0].strip()]

But accessing them as:

item_id_to_idx[str(x.strip().split("\t")[0])]

Comment: it was an hdfs path issue. Turns out all my dictionaries had no information in them. When I tested it earlier, I tried it on my local machine which did not have an hdfs path so it was able to read the file and return the dictionaries. I used cat = subprocess.Popen([ "hdfs","fs","-cat","path") and subsequently cat.stdout to read each line. This was mentioned in another SO post but I am unable to find it now unfortunately.